# How do I use User settings and Custom Configuration Sections in app.config?

Tags: c#

How do I use, User settings and Custom Configuration Sections in app.config?

```
 <mySection id="myId">
    <item1 data="info">
    <item2 data="more info">
</mySection>
```

And link them to a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app.config**

Where do key value pairs go?

```
appSettings
```

How? give example

```
 <add key="File_Count" value="2" />
```

**.cs**

What class gives access to user settings?

```
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```

What must the Project reference?

```
 System.Configuration
```

Which method gives the basic settings? Example for the above

```
 AppSettings["File_Count"]
```

Given the following custom section

```
 <mySection id="myId">
    <item1 data="info">
    <item2 data="more info">
</mySection>
```

What is needed to declare this in the app file, for a class type called "Sample.myType" in "myAssembly"?

```
<configSections>
  <section name="mySection" type="Sample.myType, myAssembly" />
</configSections>
```

What is the mapping of xml element mapping to c# attributes?

```
mySection   ConfigurationSection
item Type   ConfigurationElement
```

What is the mapping of xml property to c# attribute ?

```
id      ConfigurationProperty 
data    ConfigurationProperty
item1   ConfigurationProperty
item2   ConfigurationProperty
```

How to declare the class for the type 'myType'?

```
public class myType : ConfigurationSection {
```

How to declare a simple property 'id'?

```
//Inside myType as
[ConfigurationProperty("id", IsRequired = false)]
public string Id {
    get { return (string)this["id"];  }
    set { this["id"]=value;}
}
```

How to declare the type for the item elements?

```
//Inside myType as a sub class
public class myTypeElement : ConfigurationElement {
       [ConfigurationProperty("data", IsRequired = false)]
       public string Data {
            get { return (string)this["data"];  }
            set { this["data"]=value;}
        }
}
```

How to declare the item elements?

```
[ConfigurationProperty("item1)]
public myTypeElement Item1{
        get { return (myTypeElement)this["item1"] }
        set { this["item1"]=value;}
}
```

How to access these from the group name "mySection"?

```
Sample.myType t = (Sample.myType)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("mySection");
string s = t.item1.data;
```

Where is this in MSDN, and others?

*How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection*

*msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx*

*blog.danskingdom.com/adding-and-accessing-custom-sections-in-your-c-app-config/*